# How do I check which rows and columns are equal to ones in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have an exercise print how many pairs of indexes (i, j) have only ones in the i-th row and the j-th column and print all the pairs
For example

```
1 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

So I have to print out (0, 0); (2, 0); (3, 0) and then print out the number of pairs.

The exercise is in C
This is what I have so far

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(A[i][j] == 1 && A[i+1][j+1] == 1){
            br++;
            printf("(%d, %d)\n",i,j);
        }
    }
}
printf("%d",br);
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What issue did you find ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could actually organise the input in a matrix and clarify the example. I cannot guess what you're supposed to do

Comment: Looks like your expected output does not match the input.

Comment: I'm stuck on the IF condition

Comment: It looks like you just want `if(A[i][j] == 1 ) ...`.  Why are you referencing `A[i+1][j+1]`?  How is that cell relevant?

Comment: Start by writing two functions: `bool rowIsAllOnes(int row)` and `bool columnIsAllOnes(int column)`

Answer (score 0):

In that code you're just traversing each element in the matrix and checking if it is equal to one and the element that is diagonally adjacent (moving right then down) is equal to 1 too. That output won't be the expected one, it will only give (2,0) and (2,1) as a result, and **very important: a segmentation fault**.

Notice that when you are in the last row/column, you're checking the element and the element that is diagonally right-down, which is outside the bounds of the matrix.

There are many possible solutions, but for each element you should check the whole row and column that it pertains to (using 2 loops) and checking if all the elements are one.